# Route Error: Symfony 4 No route found for "GET /blog"

Tags: php, symfony

I am having this error:

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: No route
>   found for "GET /blog" (from "http://localhost:8000/produits")

I added the annotation @Route in the method in my controller (like I saw in other website):

```
    /**
     * @Route("/blog", name="article.index")
     * @return Response
     * */
    public function index():Response
    {
       return $this->render("blog/article.html.twig", [
        "current_menu" => 'articles'
       ]);
     }
```

I tried to add methods={"GET","HEAD"} in @Route but I have the same error

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me (adding <kbd>/</kbd> to the end of route path):

```
/**
 * @Route("/blog/", name="article.index")
 * @return Response
 * */
public function index():Response
{
   return $this->render("blog/article.html.twig", [
    "current_menu" => 'articles'
   ]);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will also at least need `use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;` at the start of the file (among the other 'use' lines), Some framework setup for Route annotations could also need to be enabled. Also, how does blog/article.html.twig refer to the route or path?

A freshly installed Symfony 4 instance will need [composer require doctrine/annotations](https://github.com/doctrine/annotations) package, unless its already been installed by some other package.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#creating-routes has more details.

Comment: Also check `php bin/console debug:router`. Maybe there is a typo